# Passing an URL parameter to a href link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I have the following code working to pass a URL parameter to a form tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getQueryVariable(variable) { 
 var query = window.location.search.substring(1); 
 var vars = query.split("&"); 
 for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) { 
 var pair = vars[i].split("="); 
 if (pair[0] == variable) { 
   return pair[1]; 
    }
  }
}
 function onLoad() {
var value = getQueryVariable("ID");
var e = document.getElementById('your-field');
e.value = value;
}
</script>
```

And...

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
 <!-- your form and hidden field goes here -->
 <input type="hidden" name="your-field" id="your-field" />
```

How can I pass the same value to an HTML link so that the end result would be:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com?source=[ID]" >
```

Where [ID] is the whatever piece of code that is needed to add the parameter to the link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You should give an id to you link, like this:

```
<a id="YOUR_ID" href="#" >
```

And then you have two ways to solve the problem, use pure Javascript or use jQuery:

IF you use jquery you can use your onLoad function and inside inject the following:

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com?source=" + value;
$("#YOUR_ID").attr("href",url)
```

OR using pure javascript:

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com?source=" + value;
var element = document.getElementById('YOUR_ID');
element.setAttribute("href",url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the function onload to this:

```
function onLoad() {
   var value = getQueryVariable("ID");
   var e = document.getElementById('your-field');
   e.value = value;

   var url = "http://www.mysite.com?source=" + value;
   var element = document.getElementById('YOUR_<A>_ELEMENT_ID');
   element.setAttribute("href",url)
}
```

I'm using the piece of code that Joao Almeida suggested so his example using jQuery works good too.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi and thanks :)

Excuse my ignorance but... what should the a href tag look like?

Also, I have 3 different a href tags that need the value to be appended... will the code above work for any number of links?