# Pass a url parameter into multiple distinct a href links via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Admittedly, javascript is not my strong suit. I need to be able to append a parameter from the url into three a href links using javascript. The structure of the url will be www.mysite.com?parameter.

Currently, the links are:

`https://www.acme.com/sui?bc=QOS-B20
https://www.acme.com/sui?bc=USE-BFN
https://www.acme.com/sui?bc=USP-BFN`

The resulting links should be:

`https://www.acme.com/sui?bc=QOS-B20&sc=parameter
https://www.acme.com/sui?bc=USE-BFN&sc=parameter
https://www.acme.com/sui?bc=USP-BFN&sc=parameter`

I already have jquery loaded on the page.

I tried to follow the directions on this post: [Passing an URL parameter to a href link using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508425/passing-an-url-parameter-to-a-href-link-using-javascript) but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to ask a question or just tell us what you're working on is currently not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with jquery

```
$('.class-of-links-to-update').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+'&'+param));
});
```

`.class-of-links-to-update` is value inside class attribute on href

```
<a class="class-of-links-to-update" ....
```

I used each function to loop through results returned by jQuery.

`this` represents current element in list of results and `$(this)` will convert element into jQuery object so we can use jQuery methods to get and set attributes of HTML element.

So just execute above JavaScript to update your results.

e.g.

```
function updateHrefs(param) {
    $('.class-of-links-to-update').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+'&'+param));
    });
}
```

end then call the function when ever you want

e.g. on button click

```
$('#id-of-button').click(function(){
  updateHrefs('sc=parameter');
});
```

Comment: Cool, this is very helpful. Follow-up question. Where do I place the two code snippets? Thank you!

Comment: everything is explained, if you want you can put it on button click or on load I explained above